# Swagger generates response body on 204 (No Content)

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

Here's a delete endpoint:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "delete subscription")
@ApiResponses(value = {
                @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "Deleted", response = Void.class),
                @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found")
})
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>> delete(@PathVariable long id)
```

Springfox generates an API spec with a response body:

```
{
  "cancelled": true,
  "done": true
}
```

Obviously I want the response body spec to be blank for 204. How to achieve this?

N.B. if I change the endpoint be synchronous:

```
public void delete(@PathVariable long id)
```

then the generated API is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
.genericModelSubstitutes(ListenableFuture.class)
```

to your Docket configuration to support `ListenableFuture<T>`.

Docs: http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#genericModelSubstitutes(java.lang.Class...)

> Substitutes each generic class with it's direct parameterized type.
>   genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class) would substitute
>   ResponseEntity<MyModel> with MyModel

For example:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ListenableFuture.class);
```

Comment: It tells Springfox that `ListenableFuture` is only wrapper for the real response, so it should be ommited.